# String.Format alignment

Tags: vb.net, string-formatting

I'm having trouble aligning my four columns:

[image]

My string format for the titles works properly. When I read the next line and put it into a list, the String.Format takes the video name and creates the columns adjusting to the video names length. How can I fix this?

```
Private Sub pdPrint_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles pdPrint.PrintPage

    e.Graphics.DrawString("Movie Collection", New Font("Courier", 20, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 300, 10)

    e.Graphics.DrawString(String.Format("{0, -20} {1,-20} {2, -20} {3,-20}", "VIDEO NAME", "YEAR PRODUCED", "RUNNING TIME", "RATING"), New Font("Courier", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 10, 70)


    Using reader As New StreamReader("testing.txt")
        Dim intVertPosition As Integer = 90
        While Not reader.EndOfStream
            Dim videoName As String = reader.ReadLine()
            Dim yearProduced As String = reader.ReadLine()
            Dim runningTime As String = reader.ReadLine()
            Dim rating As String = reader.ReadLine()
            Dim extraline As String = reader.ReadLine()


            e.Graphics.DrawString(String.Format("{0, -30} {1,30} {2, 30} {3,30}", videoName.ToString(), yearProduced.ToString(), runningTime.ToString(), rating.ToString()), New Font("Courier", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 10, intVertPosition)
            intVertPosition += 14
        End While
    End Using


End Sub
```

Comment: You didnt describe what exactly is wrong, but `String.Format` aligns within a string and not much to do with the text extent (caps vs non caps etc). That looks like a report type thing, so you could use a virtual table with 4 or 5 columns sized accordingly and justify the text within them.  Also you dont need to do `ToString()` on a string and making a `New Font` for each line is going to leak resources.

Comment: The report objects aren't lining up correctly. If I type Guardians of the Galaxy it will create the columns after the video name. So if i type a different movie like Tremors, they won't align at all besides the "Video name".

Comment: I would use tables, but unfortunately my assignment rubric specifically docks points off for using anything but String.Format

Comment: Make sure you read the assigment correctly.  `String.Format` - which is not the right thing to use here - is very different from `System.Drawing.StringFormat` which *would* be the right thing to use for printing (and virtual columns).  But yeah, *after* you read [Ask] and take the [tour] post an image.

Comment: You just mis-typed the formatting for the column headers, using 20 instead of 30.

Comment: Firstly, when you output the titles you are using 20 as the width for each column and when you output the records you are using 30.  Surely you want the same width for both.  Secondly, are you saying, without actually saying, that you want the text in a column to be a maximum of 30 (or maybe 20) and so text longer that that must be truncated?  That's not going to happen by magic, i.e. `String.Format` will pad short text but it won't truncate long text.  You have to check for yourself whether a `String` is too long and call `Substring` if it is.

Comment: I apologize again for not knowing How to Ask, I edited my post to add the picture. I hope this clarifies the problem. Thank you again, you guys rock!

Comment: I think that the file contains spaces in the lines. Just do `Trim()` when reading from a file.

Answer (score 2):

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(..., New Font("Courier", 20, FontStyle.Bold), ...)
```

This is where the problem started.  This kind of formatting can only work correctly if the width a space is the same as the width of a letter.  Or in other words, it requires a *fixed-pitch* font.  But you can clearly tell from the screen-shot that you got a proportionally pitched font.  So, roughly, the more text in the first column, the more it pushes out the next column.

This happened because you picked "Courier".  It is the name of a legacy *device font*, useful only in programs that were written 27 years ago.  Graphics.DrawString() requires a scalable font outline, a True-Type font to be specific, and cannot use device fonts.  So the font mapper kicks in to provide an alternative, unfortunately it isn't smart enough to recognize that you wanted a fixed-pitch font.

Fix the problem by using "Courier New" instead.

Comment: Courier New is kind of, well, ugly. A newer monospace font like Andale Mono, Monaco, Consolas, or Droid Sans Mono might look better, if you know you can have them available. Additionally, it seems okay here (both are Courier 12, and bold shouldn't matter), but it's worth mentioning to be careful to use the _same_ font and size between the header and body, or spacing won't line up.